# How to disable back button in Activity and reactivate after loading Fragments?

Tags: android, android-orientation

The code I used below works well, but when the screen orientation gets changed, `isback` becomes false again and turns into obsolete as well.

What I've tried so far:

```
boolean isback =false;

fragmentShowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isback = true;
        fragmentsShow();
    }
});

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {     
    if(isback == true) {
         super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

And I don't want to use `isVisible` methods of Fragments, because I have to check so many Fragments in one activity and I can't tag all of them.

Comment: When the screen orientation changes, the activity restarts. Try using [Share Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref) if you want to store the some important data, even after activity closes. Read about the Activity Lifecycle for more understanding.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem with the  Share Preferences

Comment: The data stored in Shared preferences will be not deleted even after your app is closed. Use it wisely.

Comment: Aww It has another problem I have to set isBack to false in every fragments(more than 30) which create MainActivity(Originally, it was ResultActivity). The problem was solved anyway. Thank you

Comment: @mouse1 You could extend all your fragments from a base class, and set the flag there.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity restarts when screen orientation changes, causing `isBack` value to be false.

Simply add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity details in the manifest.
This will tell your activity not to recreate itself when rotating.

[More reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)